# enumerate, overlays and beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, overlays

I would like to understand the following behaviour of enumerate in beamer. The following example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\marca}{\onslide<2>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\clubsuit$\qquad}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
My list

\begin{enumerate}
\item\marca One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

shows a list. I would like that first overlay shows the numbered list, and the second overlay shows the clubsuit on first item. However, first number does not appear.

If I change my command `\marca` in the following way

```
\newcommand{\marca}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\overlay<2>{$\clubsuit$\qquad}}}
```

then I get what I want. But I don't understand why. Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Your macro **`\uncover`** the `\makebox{}` stuff on slide 2, therefore is "covered" on slide 1, but is just there,  hiding the number of the item.

If you change `\onslide` by `\uncover` or `\visible`you obtain a similar effect. But if you change `\onslide` by  `\only`, then `\makebox` will be *only* on slide 2, and the problem disappear:

```
\newcommand{\marca}{%
\only<2>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\clubsuit$\qquad}}
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `\onslide*` instead of `\only` to obtain the same result (run `texdoc beamer`, see page 80).

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the following, the first number in the list appeared:

```
\newcommand{\marca}{\mbox{}\onslide<2>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\clubsuit$\qquad}}}
```

Added `\mbox{}` just before `\onslide` command.